# issue when opening wav file using (Java) AudioInputStream

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound

I am using JDK7 and trying to run a wav file - I tried the following test but got the error copied below:

**Error:**

```
line with format ULAW 8000.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  not supported.
```

**Sample Code:**

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

      try {
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                  new File("C://Users//xyz//Desktop//centerClosed.wav"));
          clip.open(inputStream);
          clip.start(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Any ideas on how I go about handling this case?  Thanks in advance

Comment: wondering if it is related to availability of codecs on my computer or something else?

Comment: [Related question on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java.gui/ObHGnLs_YU0)(quite different exception, but the answer is interesting) - Read the answer by @AndrewThompson: _Java sound generally only deals with 44.1KHz,
stereo, 16 bit sound.  I generally have to
*convert* any sound format to the above mentioned
parameters before JavaSound will deal with it.

This can be done, entirely within the code,
regardless of the original source format._

Comment: Audacity is a good free tool for converting audio files for this sort of thing (my go-to resource). Be careful to download it from a valid source. There is also a page on the Java Tutorials that is specifically about format conversions, very much worth reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `wav` file seems to be in ULAW format, sampled at 8kHz, a format the clip apparently does not understand.

Try converting the audio to 44.1kHz PCM like this:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

try {
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream ulawIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            new File("C://Users//xyz//Desktop//centerClosed.wav"));

    // define a target AudioFormat that is likely to be supported by your audio hardware,
    // i.e. 44.1kHz sampling rate and 16 bit samples.
    AudioInputStream pcmIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100f, 16, 1, 2, 44100f, true)
            ulawIn);

    clip.open(pcmIn);
    clip.start(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: will try later - thank you for reverting. I had to drop off that project but will update this if it works.  I was trying to convert the format (that was the end goal) between ULAW to ALAW. However, simply converting sing the audio stream did not work for me for some reason and I was not sure if I had to convert first to PCM and then back to ALAW (from what I recall, I could not get that to work either)